# Intelligently switch between multiple BASH processes

Tags: bash, background-process, suspend, process-management

Say you're in a directory and you want to check something in another directory, so you type `bash` to spawn a new shell so you can `cd` and check that thing and then type `exit` to get out and go back to the original shell still in that old directory.

Is there any way to keep both bashes running and switch between the two, sort of like Ctrl+Z + `fg`/`bg`?

Comment: Ideas: open a new terminal or terminal tab; use `screen` and create a new screen; use `pushd` and `popd`, or `cd -`

Comment: Also see [What is a fast command line way to switch between multiple directories for system administration?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286351/135943)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `suspend` command to background the child shell and return to the parent shell.

Comment: `suspend` & `fg` & `bg` will do, but they don't support interactive or ncurses-like processes.

Comment: @0xSheepdog, you can suspend an interactive ncurses based program just fine.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this:

1. If you are behind the physical console, just switch to a different TTY.
2. If you are not behind the console and you are using a graphical interface, just start a new `xterm`.
3. If you are SSH-d in or do not like either of the first two, you can:

   - Start `screen` (old, spaghetti code, but well tested).
   - Start TMUX (A modern `screen`-like replacement)
   - If the original program does not need input, suspend it (e.g. <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>) and then tell it to continue running in the background (`bg`). If you wish you can switch between tasks by suspending the current one and bringing the desired task to the foreground (`fg`).  E.g. use `jobs` and `fg %1`, `fg %2`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app/command you should look into is **screen**. It will let you detach a shell session which continues to execute on its own.

http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen