# Create shorcuts in a terminal to navigate between folders

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, cd-command

I am looking a way to create shortcuts for the `cd` command. My goal is to go quickly to distant folders. I have a new (big) drive which is not in my /home folder (but in /media/user/xxX/yyy/) and I need to access all the time to this location.

Is it possible to create a command such as "cd my_distant_folder" which save my the time to write the entire path?

I already thought about alias in my ~./bash_aliases but it would be a new command and not an argument of the `cd` command.

Comment: Probably helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286351/what-is-a-fast-command-line-way-to-switch-between-multiple-directories-for-syste

Answer (score 1):

```
export CDPATH="/media/user/xxX/yyy/"
```