# How to get pushd programs to display directory abbreviations

Tags: pushd

I'm a big fan of using bash's pushd, popd, and dirs program set.  However, I tend to use it so much, that the list of directories becomes too hard to read through.

It would be nice if I could get the dirs operation to use aliases in addition to the default home directory ~.  For example, if I move around a lot in the subdirectories of ~/Documents/MyBaseDir/MyCodeCheckout, then instead of...

```
user1> dirs
~/Documents/MyBaseDir/MyCodeCheckout/src/main/resource, ~/Documents/MyBaseDir/MyCodeCheckout/src/test/java/testdir1
```

...I'd like to get dirs (and pushd and popd) to display something like:

```
user1> dirs
~code1/src/main/resource, ~code1/src/test/java/testdir1
```

Notice in this post, that the latter output doesn't even need a scroll bar.  In the typical command prompt window, it would cut down significantly on wrapping, which is a pain to decipher.

I've recently found the -v flag to the dirs command, which makes the above output look like this:

```
user1> dirs -v
0  ~/Documents/MyBaseDir/MyCodeCheckout/src/main/resource
1  ~/Documents/MyBaseDir/MyCodeCheckout/src/test/java/testdir1
```

This would be sufficient, and I can get this behavior by default by using:

```
alias dirs='dirs -v'
```

The only downside to that is that I can't find a way to get pushd or popd to use the same format when they display the same list.  Despite bash documentation saying that a dirs operation is performed upon successful completion of both commands, it seems that the alias above does not expand into their realm.

Any further ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286351/what-is-a-fast-command-line-way-to-switch-between-multiple-directories-for-syste?